# Extract MPMoviePlayerViewController audio to keep listening in background

Tags: ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

First of all I've been searching a solution for my issue a few days (including here). I found a few topics that deal with the same problem but they are not resolving mine at all.

I'm developing an app that plays mp4 videos stored in the app and also mp4 online videos.

I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController in order to play the videos and works perfect when I am in the app but the problem comes when I push home button (background). The sound stops and my goal is to keep listening the video audio when I am not in the app (when the Iphone is locked or when I am in the background).

I've configured the options to keep listening the audio in the background in the plist file, and also tryed to create an audio session but nothing works.

I found on my searches that apple does not allow to keep playing video when your are not in the app and to achieve this you have to do something like detach the audio  and keep playing it without the video, and then, when the user comes back to the app, resume the video from the audio moment where it is, but I could not find much info about this method.

I have created a sample project to try different things to do it, and for the moment my code is this:

h. file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioSession *audioPlayer;




@end
```

m. file

```
-(void)playVideo {

NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video"
                                                   ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
_moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
int posTitulo = (int) roundf(self.titleLabel.frame.origin.y);
int altTitulo = (int) roundf(self.titleLabel.frame.size.height);
int anchTitulo = (int) roundf(self.titleLabel.frame.size.width);
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,posTitulo+altTitulo, anchTitulo, anchTitulo *         0.65);
[_moviePlayer play];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];

NSError *activationError = nil;
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&activationError];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];


}
```

If someone has achieved something like that, I would appreciate his help.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.

I used AVPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayerController, with this "guide" from apple developer website :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html